# improving linq query with groupby and first()

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, orm, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query which I'm grouping and retrieving the first result, where I think the issue is happening and the query timeouts for larger amount of data:

This is the query:

```cs
var result = await base.GetAllPagedAndSortedQueryBuilder(input)
    .Include(x => x.Person)
    .WhereIf(input.EventId.HasValue, x => x.Race.EventId == input.EventId)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.JuryRoleId, x.PersonId })
    .Select(s => new RaceJuryDto
    {
        Id = s.First().Id,
        Distance = s.Sum(r => Convert.ToDouble(r.Distance)).ToString(),
        PersonId = s.First().Person.Guid,
        Status = s.First().Status,
        JuryRoleId = s.First().JuryRoleId,
        JuryPersonId = s.First().Person.Id,
        CountRacesJury = s.GroupBy(s => s.JuryRoleId).Count(),
        AddressCity = s.First().Person.Address.City,
        RaceIds = s.Select(s => s.RaceId).ToList(),
        RaceJuryIds = s.Select(s => s.Id).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

It works 'ok' with not a lot of data but when we test against larger datasets is timing out. I think the issue is when calling the First() for each property.

Does someone have a recommendation what to do about this and how I can improve the query?

Comment: As usual, look at the generated query, investigate the query plan and proper indexing. Performance issues can hardly ever be diagnosed based on just one LINQ statement. That said, what's the source of this `WhereIf` method?

Comment: Issue here that SQL group by do not allow getting first element of the group `s.First()` and even worse - get group items `s.Select(s => s.RaceId).ToList()`.
EF Core is trying to translate this query and usually it is very ineffective. 

In your case when you need `First` - move this field to the grouping key
If you need grouping sub elements - consider to do grouping on the client side.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Wow, yes, the translation is shocking with cartesian explosion and all. I see that `AsSplitQuery()` may be a great improvement.

Comment: @GertArnold, fastest way is to grab only needed fields from database and group data on the client side.